When I publish to npm, then install in another project, the app directory is missing
I published https://github.com/masonstevens95/nextjs-float-menu/ as @masonstevens95/nextjs-float-menu. When I try to install it as a dependency on another project, the src and app directories are missing, and I get
Cannot find module '@masonstevens95/nextjs-float-menu' or its corresponding type declarations.

Here is a snip of the node_modules:

package.json for nextjs-float-menu:
{
  "name": "@masonstevens95/nextjs-float-menu",
  "version": "0.1.2",
  "author": {
    "name": "Prabhu Murthy",
    "email": "prabhu.m.murthy@gmail.com"
  },
  "contributors": [
    {
      "name": "Mason Stevens",
      "email": "mason.c.stevens@gmail.com",
      "url": "https://github.com/masonstevens95"
    }
  ],
  "homepage": "https://github.com/prabhuignoto/react-float-menu",
  "license": "MIT",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/prabhuignoto/react-float-menu"
  },
  "description": "Smart draggable floating menu component for React",
  "keywords": [
    "react",
    "float",
    "menu",
    "smart menu",
    "floating menu",
    "draggable menu"
  ],
  "publishConfig": {
    "registry": "https://registry.npmjs.org/",
    "cache": "cache/.npm"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "npx serve@latest ./build",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "build:dev": "webpack --config webpack.config.js --mode development",
    "build:prod": "webpack --config webpack.config.js --mode production",
    "webpack:dev": "webpack --config webpack.config.js --mode development",
    "lint:js": "eslint src/**/*.tsx",
    "lint:js-fix": "eslint src/**/*.tsx --fix",
    "lint:css": "stylelint src/**/*.scss",
    "lint:css-fix": "stylelint --fix src/**/*.scss",
    "lint:all": "pnpm lint:js && pnpm lint:css",
    "format": "prettier --write src/**/*.{tsx,scss}",
    "snyk:monitor": "pnpm dlx snyk monitor",
    "snyk:test": "pnpm dlx snyk test",
    "test": "pnpm vitest run -c ./vitest.config.ts",
    "cypress:open": "pnpm dlx cypress open",
    "cypress:quiet": "pnpm exec cypress run --headless --quiet --browser chrome",
    "test:dev": "vitest watch -c ./vitest.config.ts --silent",
    "test:coverage": "vitest run -c ./vitest.config.ts --coverage"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "last 2 versions",
    "not op_mini all",
    "not ie <= 11"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "classnames": "^2.3.2",
    "nanoid": "^4.0.2",
    "next": "^14.2.5",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "main": "dist/react-float-menu.js",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.22.9",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.22.9",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.9",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.22.5",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.22.5",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.22.6",
    "@testing-library/dom": "^9.3.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.3",
    "@types/node": "^20.4.2",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "@types/testing-library__jest-dom": "^5.14.8",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.1.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.1.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.3",
    "@vitest/coverage-v8": "^0.33.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.20",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.3",
    "babel-plugin-remove-attribute": "^1.0.0",
    "c8": "^8.0.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^11.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^6.8.1",
    "cypress": "^12.17.1",
    "eslint": "^8.45.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.8.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.13.3",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.27.5",
    "eslint-plugin-n": "^16.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^6.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
    "eslint-plugin-sort-keys-fix": "^1.1.2",
    "fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin": "^8.0.0",
    "husky": "^8.0.3",
    "jsdom": "^22.1.0",
    "lint-staged": "^13.2.3",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.7.6",
    "postcss": "^8.4.41",
    "postcss-loader": "^7.3.3",
    "postcss-preset-env": "^9.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.63.6",
    "sass-loader": "^13.3.2",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.3",
    "stylelint": "^15.10.1",
    "stylelint-config-prettier": "^9.0.5",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^34.0.0",
    "stylelint-config-standard-scss": "^10.0.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.9",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.9",
    "ts-loader": "^9.4.4",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6",
    "typescript-plugin-css-modules": "^5.0.1",
    "vite": "^4.4.4",
    "vitest": "^0.33.0",
    "webpack": "^5.88.2",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.9.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^3.0.0"
  }
}

package.json for project I am using it in:
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@dnd-kit/core": "^6.1.0",
    "@masonstevens95/nextjs-float-menu": "^0.1.2",
    "@react-spring/parallax": "^9.7.3",
    "@react-spring/types": "^9.7.3",
    "@react-spring/web": "^9.7.3",
    "@react-three/fiber": "^8.16.8",
    "@types/react": "^18.3.3",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.3.0",
    "@vis.gl/react-google-maps": "^1.1.0",
    "auth": "^1.0.2",
    "next": "^14.1.0",
    "next-auth": "^4.24.6",
    "nextjs-toploader": "^1.6.11",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-float-menu": "^0.4.7",
    "react-toggle-slider": "^0.4.0",
    "three": "^0.166.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/three": "^0.166.0",
    "typescript": "5.4.5"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "react-google-maps": {
      "typescript": "$typescript"
    },
    "@react-google-maps/api": {
      "typescript": "$typescript"
    }
  }
}


They didn't disappear when you installed the package, they were missing when you created the package. Share your package.json

@Evert
Edited post with package.json

also, what do you mean exactly? I have built it and run it on my local. Why does it not build when creating the package?

Your package.json states that you only ship the dist directory via the files property.  You need to include src and app if you want those directories to be included as well.
